# I have in a program two recursions and as for me evrything should be fine, but it gives me wrong answer at the end. JS

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here is a task

Say you have an array prices for which the ith element is the price of a given stock on day i.

Design an algorithm to find the maximum profit. You may complete as many transactions as you like (i.e., buy one and sell one share of the stock multiple times).

Note: You may not engage in multiple transactions at the same time (i.e., you must sell the stock before you buy again).

```
    Example 1:
    

Input: [7,1,5,3,6,4]
    Output: 7
    Explanation: Buy on day 2 (price = 1) and sell on day 3 (price = 5), profit = 5-1 = 4.
                 Then buy on day 4 (price = 3) and sell on day 5 (price = 6), profit = 6-3 = 3.
    Example 2:


Input: [1,2,3,4,5]
Output: 4
Explanation: Buy on day 1 (price = 1) and sell on day 5 (price = 5), profit = 5-1 = 4.
             Note that you cannot buy on day 1, buy on day 2 and sell them later, as you are
             engaging multiple transactions at the same time. You must sell before buying again.
    Example 3:
    
Input: [7,6,4,3,1]
Output: 0
Explanation: In this case, no transaction is done, i.e. max profit = 0.
```

Here is my solution with explanation and explanation of a problem, I know there is a lot to try to understand

```
    /**
     * @param {number[]} prices
     * @return {number}
     */
     // already creating iterator to go through every element in array
        var maxProfit = function(prices, i = 0, curSum = 0, maxSum = 0) {
            if(i >= prices.length- 1) // exiting condition
                return maxSum;
// to check array el. with every next possible number and create recursion to see if that's the maximum Profit
            for(let j = i + 1; j < prices.length; ++j) 
                {
                   if(prices[j] - prices[i] > 0)
                       {
                            curSum += prices[j] - prices[i]; 
                            if(curSum > maxSum) 
                                maxSum = curSum;
                            console.log('Im inside loop', curSum); 
// here is an **error**, it works fine and even gives desired result **7**, but I don't know how and where it gives one more answer 9. By all my understanding it shouldn't. Can anybody explain where it gets 9?? I tried track it and console log it, but all in vain 
                            maxProfit(prices, ++j, curSum, maxSum);
                       }
                }
            return maxProfit(prices, ++i, 0, maxSum);
        };
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework.  (In the future please label it so.)  Perhaps it would be cleaner to reduce your array into a collection of subarrays which are increasing, something like, `[[7], [1, 5], [3, 6], [4]]` for your first example.  Then for each section you can subtract the first value from the last (which will be zero for any singletons) and add the results together.  This breakdown could be recursive or use `reduce`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets imagine we make a function called square:

```
function square(a) {
  return a * a;
}
```

We then use it in a function in the same manner as you call your recursive function:

```
function test(b) {
  square(b);
  return b;
}
```

When calling this it just return its argument:

```
test(5); // ==> 5
```

The reason is that the result of the `square(b)` is never used. It did the calculation and it was returned to `test`, but `test` didn't use that result for anything. It could be different if `square` did side effects, but it doesn't and thus in `test` the line `square(b)` is dead code.

In your function you are calling `maxProfit(prices, ++j, curSum, maxSum)` and you never use the result for a variable or return it. Thus the line doesn't do anything. The desired result `7` is discarded because you never use it for anything.

I guess some people get confused since the function they call is the same as the callee, but recursive functions get **no special treatment**. They work the same as all other funcitons. They wait until the result eventually is returned at each level as if they had called a completely different function that returned th ecorrect answer. Even if `i` is increasing in the recursive calls, when the result comes back to the first callee `i` is still zero. Each local variable is unique for that call and one call does not interfere with another, unless you do something exotic like mutation of global state or member variables. One `return` only goes one step back. Eg. even if `square` returns it does not also return from `test`.